# Окна в processing

Tags: processing

Программа должна открывать и закрывать окна с помощью переключателя. С тем чтобы открыть окно проблем нет, но закрыть не удается, функция которая отвечает за выход не вызывается.

```
import controlP5.*;

ControlP5 cp5;

PWindow one;
public void setup() {
  size(800, 400);
  cp5 = new ControlP5(this);
  one = null;
//переключатель 1
  cp5.addIcon("icon", 10)
    .setPosition(100, 100)
    .setSize(70, 50)
    .setRoundedCorners(20)
    .setFont(createFont("fontawesome-webfont.ttf", 40))
    .setFontIcons(#00f205, #00f204)
    //.setScale(0.9,1)
    .setSwitch(true)
    .setColorBackground(color(255, 100))
    .hideBackground()
    ;
}
void draw() {
    background(220);
}

public void icon(boolean theValue) {
  println("got an event for icon", theValue);
  if (theValue){
    one = new PWindow();
  }//else test(); // функция не определена но если вызвать exit(); то закроется вся программа
}

public class PWindow extends PApplet {
  PWindow() {
    super();
    PApplet.runSketch(new String[] {this.getClass().getSimpleName()}, this);
  }
    void settings() {
    size(240, 78);
  }
    void setup() {
    background(150);
    windowMove(0, 0);
  }
    void draw() {
    ellipse(random(width), random(height), random(50), random(50));
  }
  
  public void test(){
  exit();
  }
    public void exit()
  {
    dispose();
  }
 }
```